Trigger navigation externally on SPA application that uses React Router
I need to go on multiple pages of a SPA application (Grafana) with a headless browser (Puppeteer). Grafana uses React-Router for its navigation.
Using page.goto works fine but reloads the full application each time which is really slow. I have thousands of pages to go through so I would like to find a faster way.
So I tried instead history.pushState (directly in the browser console) but this just changes the URL in the browser UI and doesn't trigger any navigation event from the application.
I found solutions that work when one can change the code of the target SPA but this is not my situation, I don't want to change Grafana UI code.
Is there a way to trigger a navigation in a React Router application outside the application? From the console would be fine.
In my particular case this is React Router 5.3.3 but a generic solution might exist.
Grafana attaches a LocationService to window._debug in non-production builds (github), and one can call .push(string) on this location service to trigger a navigation, but I will need this on a production build.

No, not really. I think the post you linked is about the only way to do this, using an externally created history object that the internal router would also use. If you can't change the source code to use a history router and pass a history object to the app, then I'm afraid the option is to just use normal browser navigation actions.
